# Missing label in twin axes (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am studying an ebook about matplotlib, and I have a problem with one example concerning twin axes.
The code is this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0., np.e, 0.01)
y1 = np.exp(-x)
y2 = np.log(x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x, y1)
ax1.set_ylabel('Y values for exp(-x)')

ax2 = ax1.twinx() # this is the important function

ax2.plot(x, y2, 'r')
ax2.set_xlim([0, np.e])
ax2.set_ylabel('Y values for ln(x)')
ax2.set_xlabel('Same X for both exp(-x) and ln(x)')

plt.show()
```

The result is this, the x label seems missing:

[image: matplolib twin axes missing label]

I run the code in Pycharm.
Is there a reason for the missing label?

Thanks

Comment: That is ....odd.  I _suspect_ this is from code that makes sure you can't end up with over-lapping xlabels.

Comment: I noticed that the book I am reading was published in 2009. Maybe in the old versions of matplotlib it was possible to put the label in both the axes, and later this changed, perhaps to avoid possible conflicts, as you say?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why, but it showed up for me when I put it in ax1 instead.

```
ax1.set_xlabel('Same X for both exp(-x) and ln(x)')
```

Comment: I just tried, and you are right, putting the label on ax1 does work.
It would be interesting to know the reason.